# Creating a general list of ascending and descending numbers using list comprehension

Tags: python, arrays, list-comprehension

I am trying to generate a list containing a mixture of ascending and descending numbers.

e.g., say you have `n=5`.  I want to generate a list/array based on `n` such that you have:

```
[0,1,2,3,4,3,2,1,0]
```

using list comprehension.

I tried doing this:

```
print [[i+j] for i in range(n)for j in range(n,-1,-1)]
```

but I can't seem to get it right.

Comment: why wouldnt you just do `range(n) + range(n-2,-1,-1)`

Comment: @JoranBeasley or to use `n` like the op is hoping for: `range(n) + range((n-1), -1, -1)`

Comment: You really don't want to use `[... for i in range(X) for j in range(Y)]` because you just doubly nested the `for` loops, so you get `X*Y` total loops.  This will generate too many numbers; you are actually trying to generate `2*n - 1` numbers.

Comment: I like `range(n)[:-1] + range(n)[::-1]`

Comment: FYI there is a generalised version of this 'triangle window' in the function `scipy.signal.triang`

Answer (score 5):

I know you specified you wanted a list comp, but is it really necessary?

```
list(range(5)) + list(reversed(range(4)))
```

(python 3 syntax)

Or, in python2:

```
range(5) + range(4)[::-1]
```

or

```
range(5) + range(3,-1,-1)
```

I think the first one is more readable, but ymmv.

Answer (score 2):

```
In [27]: n = 5

In [28]: [n-1-abs(i-n+1) for i in range(n*2-1)]
Out[28]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

#### Update

This one might be more clear

```
In [36]: [n-abs(i) for i in range(-n,n+1)]
Out[36]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Comment: `[n - abs(i) - 1 for i in range(1 - n, n)]`

Answer (score 0):

One-liner:

```
[i if i < n else 2*(n-1)-i for i in range(2*(n-1) + 1)]
```

More efficient:

```
_top = 2*(n-1)
[i if i < n else _top-i for i in range(_top + 1)]
```